# What return type should I use for a pointer assignment?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a struct like this:

```
struct group
{
    int index; 
    string name; 
    group* child;

};
```

And I set up a vector to store some group structs.

Now I am trying to have a function to retrieve a group member from that vector by index, something like this:

```
148    newGroup.child = getGroupByIndex(world, i);
```

And the definition of the function is :

```
group& getGroupByIndex(vector<group>* world, int i)
{
    for(vector<group>::iterator it = world->begin();
        it < world->end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->index == i) return *it;
    }
267     return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, it won't even compile.

And the error message is :

```
tree.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 
tree.cpp:148: error: cannot convert ‘group’ to ‘group*’ in assignment 
tree.cpp: In function ‘group& getGroupByIndex(std::vector<group, std::allocator<group> >*, int)’: 
tree.cpp:267: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘group&’ from a temporary of type ‘int’
```

My two problems,

1. how to fix the compile error? what return type should I use?
2. If I want to return a null pointer in line 267, what should I use? I tried (void *)0 and 0, but neither works.

Comment: References are different from pointers. Assigning a reference to a pointer does not work. A reference to 0 does not work (null pointers do not apply to references because they're two different things). A non-const reference to a temporary does not work. You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c).

Comment: This is a questionable desing, IMO. But to solve your immediate problem: take the adress of the `group` your function returns: `&getGroupByIndex(world, i);` Be careful with the adress if your function doesn't find the element with the index you searched for. You also can't return 0 from the function, obviously.

Comment: I am not a C++ guy but AFAIK you should return `null` or any pointer value(reference) rather than 0.Because pointer is a reference and the returning value is a primitive value.and this part of error `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘group&’ from a temporary of type ‘int’` also saying the same thing , I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
group* getGroupByIndex(vector<group*> world, int i) // See position of two *
{
    for(vector<group*>::iterator it = world.begin();
        it < world.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->index == i)
          return *it;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
group* getGroupByIndex(vector<group> *world, int i) // See position of two *
{
    for(vector<group>::iterator it = world->begin();
        it < world->end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->index == i)
          return &(*it);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is most relevant, I believe. At least compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you want prefer references to pointers, you can also define a "not found" group object that will be returned by your function.

I would do that like this :

```
struct group
{
    int index; 
    string name; 
    group* child;
    group(int i):index(i),child(null){}
    group(int i, const string& n, group& c):index(i), name(n), child(&c){}

    // assuming index defines the uniqueness of your object class
    bool operator == (const struct group& g)const {return (index == g.index);}

    // an unique special instance of group struct
    static struct group not_found;
};
group group::not_found(-1);
```

thus you can define your function the way you wanted :

```
group& getGroupByIndex(vector<group>* world, int i)
{
    for(vector<group>::iterator it = world->begin();
        it < world->end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->index == i) return *it;
    }
    return group::not_found; // a reference to a special singleton instance of struct group
}
```

and you will be able to make calls like this :

```
...
group& g = getGroupByIndex(world, index);
if(g == group::not_found)
{
   // handle the not found case here
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use

`boost::optional`

### First rule of modern C++ : Don't use ****ing pointers.

```
boost::optional<group&> get(vector<group>& world, int i)
{
    for(auto & grp : world)
    {
        if(grp.index == i)
           return boost::optional<group&>(grp);
    }
    return boost::none;
}
```

Please note that this solution has `O(n)` complexity. If you want to search basing on `index`, I'd recommend  using a structure that has references to `group` objects sorted by `index`, which would give you `O(log n)` lookup time.

In that case, I'd probably hold a vector of `shared_ptr`s and a `map<int, weak_ptr>`. You could also take a look at `boost::multi_index`

Ah, and just a sidenote to your `2)` point I've just noticed : `nullptr`.